# Print diamond shape in Java

Tags: java, performance, ascii-art

I'm printing a diamond shape in Java. It's working fine, but is there a way to re-write this code to make it faster?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = sc.nextInt();

sc.close();

String ns = String.valueOf(n);
int z = n/2;

int k = n%2;


for (int j = 0 ; j<n;j++) {

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < k ; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    if (i==k-1)
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    if ((k-n)==0)
        break;
    z--;
    k=k+2;

}

 z = (n)/2;

 k = (n)%2;
int w = k;
int y = n-2;

for (int j = 0 ; j<z  ;j++) {

    for (int i = 0 ; i<w;i++)
    System.out.print(" ");


    for (int i = 0 ; i< y ;i++)
        System.out.print("*");
    w=w+1;
    y=y-2;

    System.out.print("\n");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Can you define what you expect by "faster"? This is a pretty vague term. Fewer operations (likely)? Improved Big O (unlikely)?

Comment: I meant by fewer operations

Comment: Do you use an IDE? Asking because the code is not *indented* as usual - one point of *perceivability*.

Comment: Yes I use IntelliJ , sorry for inconvenience but this is my first question to ask here and I don’t know how to indent right. :)

Comment: As already said, you need to be more specific about what is it that you expect. If you just want to tinker with the code and see how much shorter you can make it, then move your question to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: I just want the code not to use nested loops @givanse

Comment: Okay, so that is what you need to specify in your question: That you want to reduce the complexity of your solution (big O notation), ideally to a linear solution i.e. O(n). This is an algorithm design question and you may get more attention in the computer science site https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Victoria To let IntelliJ indent your code, press Ctrl+Alt+L. Take some time to try out all the other items from the main menu as well, they are worth spending some time.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code, I'll point out that:

It would be better if you used more descriptive variable names. It improves readability and might even help you better understand your own code, ex:

```
int width = sc.nextInt(); // or whatever it represents
```

Always use curly braces for `if` and `for` statements, even if they wrap around a single statement. Shorter code isn't faster, but makes it easier to introduce bugs. You never pay a penalty for extra curly braces or parentheses, so use them as much as you want to clarify intention. For example this snippet can be ambiguous:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i< y ;i++)
    System.out.print("*");
w=w+1;
y=y-2;
```

Did you mean

```
for (int i = 0 ; i< y ;i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
    w=w+1;
    y=y-2;
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0 ; i< y ;i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
w=w+1;
y=y-2;
```

Comment: I meant this one : 
 for (int i = 0 ; i< y ;i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        w=w+1;
        y=y-2;

//////////

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well for odd inputs:

```
9
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

However, the output is weirdly wrong for even inputs:

```
8
       **
  ****
 ******
********
******
 ****
  **
```

If you want to improve performance (in a way that would be noticeable to benchmarks, but not to the human eye), the most important change you should make is to reduce the number of `System.out.print()` calls.  Each `.print()` results in a system call, which would require synchronization (acquiring a lock, in case your program is multithreaded, so that the output of multiple simultaneous `.print()` calls won't get interleaved with each other), as well as context switching (putting your Java code on hold to run code in the operating system kernel).  All of that overhead is *huge*, compared to any other change you can make to your algorithm.

Therefore, for better performance, you should create a `StringBuilder` and repeatedly append the entire diamond to it, then call `System.out.println()` just once per line, or, better yet, just once at the end.  [Here is an example that prints an hourglass shape](/a/111470/9357), which is closely related to your diamond shape.

Comment: And yes I wanted an odd integer not even. I should've said that, apologies.